# How do I determine if DFS's Auto Recovery State is Actually doing anything?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, dfs-r

One of my servers was rebooted recently and CHKDSK was run.  When I run a DFS Diagnostic report on it, the DFS environment shows the server that was rebooted is now in a state of "Auto Recovery".  However, it's been in that state for over 48 hrs now.  I understand it can take some time, since the folders in the replication group have thousands of files, and they're relatively large, but 48 hrs seems pretty long.

I've read several articles about DFS start up after a "dirty" shutdown, but there are no Error 2213 or 2004 in my servers.

Also, this key: `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DFSR\Parameters\StopReplicationOnAutoRecovery` was already set to `0`

Is there a way I can see what's going on?

Is there a way I can improve performance on the Auto Recovery state?

Is there a way for me to determine if the Auto Recovery state is doing anything?